# Как в регулярном выражении исключить поиск в комментариях //?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, notepad++

Как в Nodepad++ в регулярном выражении исключить поиск в комментариях, т.е. при поиске игнорировать то, что идет после двойной косой черты (двойного слэша): //

Речь идет только о комментариях вида:  //***********

Comment: `(?!\/\/.+$)` ?

Comment: Это делается по-другому: ищете и захватываете комментарии и просто ищете что-то другое, что нужно заменить. Если нужен сам поиск, сначала удалите все комментарии, потом ищите нужный текст (например, для подсчёта совпадений/вхождений)

Comment: Notepad++ не IDE и регулярки в подобной задаче работают плохо. Когда начинаются подобные задачи, в которых важно учитывать семантику написанного - лучше использовать полноценные IDE. В остальном - руководствуйтесь подходом @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: _Регулярные_ выражения, как следует из их названия, предназначены для разбора _регулярных_ грамматик. Грамматики большинства языков программирования являются _нерегулярными_. В-общем, регексы для этого подходят плохо.